# __new__ in fractions module

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I have been trying to understand `__new__` and metaprogramming. So I had a look at official python source code.

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py

Their `__new__` function for Fractions looks like:

```
class Fraction(Rational):

    def __new__(cls, numerator=0, denominator=None):
        """Constructs a Fraction. ...        """

        self = super(Fraction, cls).__new__(cls)
        ...

        if isinstance(numerator, float):
                # Exact conversion from float
                value = Fraction.from_float(numerator)
                self._numerator = value._numerator
                self._denominator = value._denominator
                return self

    @classmethod
    def from_float(cls, f):
        """Converts a finite float to a rational number, exactly. ..."""
        # ...
        return cls(*f.as_integer_ratio())
```

Why do they `return self`, rather than

```
return Fraction.from_float(numerator)
```

I thought I understood it, but now I'm confused.

(Edit)

To support subclassing, would it make any difference to change to

```
return cls.from_float(numerator)
```

Comment: For the record, the code appears to work the same with the changes you suggested. Haven't tried any benchmarks yet, but I don't think it would be any slower to return the constructed value directly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in *Fractions* was a complicated place to start.  It is best to build up an understanding step by step.

1) object.__new__ is the root tool for creating instances of new-style classes:

```
o = object()
```

2) A class that defines __new__ typically calls object.__new__ to do its work:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        return object.__new__(cls)

a = A()
```

3) A classmethod typically relies on the class's __new__ to do its work:

```
class A(object):

    def __new__(cls):
        return object.__new__(cls)

    @classmethod
    def from_something(cls):
        return cls.__new__()
```

With that understanding in place, you can see what the fractions module is doing:

1) *from_float()* calls `cls(numerator, denominator)` to delegate the instance creation to the Fraction.__new__() method.

2) The *Fraction.__new__()* method uses *super()* to call *object.__new__()* to do the actual instance creation.

**Addenda**

@Blckknght wants to know why `value` isn't returned directly (after it is created, its numerator and demoninator are copies into `self` before the `value` is throw-away.   The answer is that `Fraction.from_float` creates an instance of *Fraction* rather than *cls*.  In other words, the code is providing support for subclassing:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> class MyFraction(Fraction):
        pass

>>> f = MyFraction(2, 3)
>>> f
Fraction(2, 3)
>>> f.__class__               # this MUST be MyFraction, not a Fraction
<class '__main__.MyFraction'>
```

**Edit**

@richard wants to know "why not use: return cls.from_float(numerator)"?

It's called the [Open-Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).  A subclasser should be able to override *from_float()* without unintentionally breaking *__init__()*:

```
>>> class MyFraction(Fraction):
        def from_float(cls, *args):
        raise NotImplemented


>>> f = MyFraction(5.75)
>>> f
Fraction(23, 4)
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point. `Fraction(1.0)` ends up creating two separate `Fraction` instances, `self` and `value`. `value` gets discarded immediately after its `_numerator` and `_denominator` values get copied over to `self`. There's no obvious reason for the `# Exact conversion` block to work that way (that I can see). Instead, it could be `return Fraction.from_float(numerator)`, which discards `self` and returns the (no longer named) `value`. Ideally, I suppose, you'd put off creating `self`, or just use `numerator.as_integer_ratio` directly, but I suspect the logic gets complicated.

Comment: Hmm, I appreciate your update. I suspect that you could still work around the subclassing issue by calling `cls.from_float` rather than `Fraction.from_float`. I suppose that would risk the possibility that a subclass would override `from_float` in some incompatible way, but if they do they're probably going to have overridden `__new__` as well, or lots of other things will probably be broken.

Comment: For subclassing, why not use: return cls.from_float(numerator)

Comment: While I agree it seems a bit obtuse, and not amazingly easy to grok when new to these things (`__new__` in itself isn't overly difficult but can still be a mental stumbling block - especially when coming from other languages), I doubt an alternative answer from such an authoritative source is going to be available :)

Comment: Problem: I want to use an improved algorithm for from_float. Because `Fraction.from_float` is hard coded in `__new__`, I would have to rewrite `__new__` AND `from_float` in order to just fix the `from_float` implementation. Does this actually break the Open-Closed Principle as it impedes modification by subclasses?